# Typescript pass subset implicit

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Assume I get from the api an object which looks like this:

```
{
  field1: null,
  field2: "foo",
  field3: 42,
  field4: {"a":"b"},
  field5: [1,2,3]
}
```

and I have a component that needs certain properties of the object, let's say field2 and field4.

Now, in reality, the data-object contains 100s of fields, and I have several components which always require a certain subset.

Is there any notation how I can pass down only the relevant fields?

What I mean:

```
type TMyData = {
      field1?: string;
      field2: string;
      field3: number;
      field4: object;
      field5: [number];
    }

type TMyDataPartial = {
      field2: string;
      field4: object;
    }
```

Main Component:

```
data: TMyData = await api.get("url");

return(
<ComponentA data={data} />
{/*more stuff*/}
);
```

and inside ComponentA I have

```
interface IProps {
  data: TMyDataPartial
}

const ComponentA = ( {data}: IProps ) => //stuff
```

This would clearly fail, since typescript-compiler tells the data type in my MyComponent differs from the one my ComponentA is expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This would clearly fail, since typescript-compiler tells the data type in my MyComponent differs from the one my ComponentA is expecting.

TypeScript doesn't care about the *names* of types, its type system is [structural](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system), not [nominal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system). That means that if you have:

```typescript
type TMyData = {
  field1?: string;
  field2: string;
  field3: number;
  field4: object;
  field5: [number];
}

type TMyDataPartial = {
  field2: string;
  field4: object;
}
```

There's no problem assigning a `TMyData` instance to a variable/parameter whose type is `TMyDataPartial`, since `TMyData` is a superset of `TMyDataPartial`:

```typescript
let data: TMyData = {
    field2: "two",
    field3: 3,
    field4: {},
    field5: [42],
};

let partial: TMyDataPartial = data; // Works just fine
console.log(partial.field2); // "two"
console.log(partial.field4); // {}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgsiAIgQ2MqBeKBvAUFKAMwEsIAbAEwEYB+ALigGdgAnYgOwHMBufI0ygCYGzNl14ES5CgGYG7AK4BbAEYQWE-tIAsDAPYqAVhADGwTVMoBWBgG1Fq9QF1eAX1y5QkWAhRoACsgswMTIZJg4fJYUwkysHDxRAhS6UAbGZm4eZBDAUBSoyAzwSIUReASSybEARMAA7no1ADR8VdJyUDKtlVqUqdiuPZXRNlC22oJOra68uDl5YEEhYcW+hYHBoeFYBWi8JnrsjHo5AHRkepwAFEtbYWfRggCU3FAA9O9QdY01uIfHU4QC5XW7LbaPZLaV4fL6DIA)

To create the `TMyDataPartial` type, you have at least four options:

1. Define `TMyDataPartial` manually, as in your example.
2. Use the [`Partial`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) utility type to create `TMyDataPartial`. But I wouldn't think it would suit your purposes, beacuse it makes **all** properties of the type optional. You seem to want a specific subset.
3. Use the [`Pick`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) utility type to create `TMyDataPartial` by specifying the names of the properties you want from `TMyData`:

   ```typescript
   type TMyDataPartial = Pick<TMyData, "field2" | "field4">;
   ```

   [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgsiAIgQ2MqBeKBvAUFKAMwEsIAbAEwEYB+ALigGdgAnYgOwHMBufI0ygCYGzNl14ES5CgGYG7AK4BbAEYQWE-tIAsDAPYqAVhADGwTVMoBWBgG1Fq9QF1eAX1y5QkWAhRoACsgswMTIZJhQ-sQmANYAPPBIqMgANFAARJYUgulQAD4ZWdrpAHy8uGQQwFAUyQyJfuhYeASSAtkM6cAA7nrpKXxt0nJQMgOtWpS6OK7jrVk2ULbagk4DruWV1WBBIWH1vsmBwaHhWLVovCZ67Ix6lQB0ZHqcABQ7J2EPWYIAlNxQAD0gIyPT6uGut3uECeL3eu1O33a2n+QJB2FcQA)

   This has the advantage that if you update the types of `field2` and/or `field4` in `TMyData`, `TMyDataPartial` is automatically kept in sync with `TMyData`.
4. Use the [`Omit`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) utility type to create `TMyDataPartial` by specifying the names of the properties you **don't** want from `TMyData`:

   ```typescript
   type TMyDataPartial = Omit<TMyData, "field1" | "field3" | "field5">;
   ```

   [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgsiAIgQ2MqBeKBvAUFKAMwEsIAbAEwEYB+ALigGdgAnYgOwHMBufI0ygCYGzNl14ES5CgGYG7AK4BbAEYQWE-tIAsDAPYqAVhADGwTVMoBWBgG1Fq9QF1eAX1y5QkWAhRoACsgswMTIZJhQAPJKxMAAPPBIqMgANFAARJbU6VAAPhlZMjn5mQIUVukAfLy4ZBDAUBTJDIl+6Fh4BJJlwhnAAO566Sl83dJyUDIjXVqUujiu011ZNlC22oJOI641dQ1gQSFhLb7JgcGh4VhNaLwmeuyMenUAdGR6nAAUBxdhL1mCACU3CgAHpQX1BulcPdHs8IG8Pt9Dpd-mVtMCwRDsK4gA)

   This has the same advantage that `Pick` has, as well as that if you add properties to `TMyData` they get added to `TMyDataPartial` as well.

For what you describe it seems like either #3 or #4 would be appropriate, depending on whether you want to use a passlist of properties (`Pick`) or a blocklist of properties (`Omit`) when creating `TMyDataPartial`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Pick` e.g.

```
interface IProps extends Pick<TMyData, keyof TMyDataPartial> {}
```